# Interprocess communication Java

Tags: java, ipc, processbuilder

I'm currently learning Java interprocess communication and it's being pretty tough for me. I need to develop a Java program that supports parameters from the console call line and return the following values with System.exit():

- If the number of parameters is <1 should return 1
- If it's a single string type parameter it should return 2
- If the parameter is an integer <0 should return 3
- Other cases should return 0

---

After doing that, I need to create a second Java program that runs the previous one, and will show on screen what has happened according to each of the parameters passed.
ATM I have this, but don't know exactly how I should continue. In console always returns 1, regardless of the parameter. 
Parameter controller class:

```
public class DameParam {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length==0)
        System.exit(1);
    else if(args.length==1 && args[0] instanceof String)
        System.exit(2);     
    else
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Console output class:

```
public class PasaParam {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb;
    Process process;
    int exitVal;
    try {
        pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.directory(new File("/home/amna/git/pspjava/PsPJava/bin/"));
        pb.command("java", "tema1.procesos.DameParam","1");
        process = pb.start();
        
        exitVal = process.waitFor();            
        System.out.println("One parameter: " + exitVal);
        
        pb.command("java", "tema1.procesos.DameParam");
        process = pb.start();           
        exitVal = process.waitFor();             
        System.out.println("No parameter " + exitVal);          
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: maybe try with `pb.inheritIO();` to see eventual errors (e.g. class not found) || BTW: `String[] args` -> `args[...]` is always an instance of String or null`(you will never get a `null` when this is being started as a (normal) java application)

Comment: [description](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/java.html#exit-status) fo the `java` tool: "*The following exit values are typically returned by the launcher when the launcher is called with the wrong arguments, serious errors, or exceptions thrown by the JVM. However, a Java application may choose to return any value by using the API call System.exit(exitValue). The values are:  - `0`: Successful completion - `>0`: An error occurred*" - it would be better to use negative values in `System.exit()`

Comment: Oh thank you so much friend. I used that method you said ( `inheritIO()` ) and the console said these lines:
_Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0._ So I changed my Java SE version to 11 and everything works now. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: class compiled with Java 18, being run with Java 11 - the one that ProcessBuilder is calling (even if it itself is running on Java 18) - that is due to PATH settings of operating system (solutions: change path settings; or use absolute path to `java` in ProcessBuilder)

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, now my program looks fine for now. Thanks for the help